# Why sticker pack displaying stickers in list wise not in grid in MSMessagesAppViewController

Tags: swift, imessage, mssticker

i'm implementing stickers pack app for i message app in swift3

my code like this

```
 func loadStickers() {
    for i in 1...6 {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "flower\(i)", withExtension: "jpg") {
            do {
                let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "")
                stickers.append(sticker)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}



func createStickerBrowser() {
    let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .large)

    addChildViewController(controller)
    view.addSubview(controller.view)

    controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self

    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

//delegates

```
func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
    return stickers.count
}

func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
    return stickers[index]
}
```

here output also coming no bugs also

but what is the problem is stickers displaying like list i need grid means each row 3 stickers i searched lot of tutorials but i failed to get can anyone help me please ..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .large)
```

Large stickers are 206 x 206 points, which means there is no room to display more than one per row on most devices. If you want a grid, use a smaller sticker size. If you want full control over the view, use a collection view with `MSStickerView` inside the cell.

Comment: how to use collection view with sticker view 

actually i created one collection view and i implemented delegates also but how t0 use in MSStickerView ..can anybody help me plase